# Set AlertDialog Positive Button Text to be Bold

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-dialog

Here is my code.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_dialog_layout,null);
    builder.setView(vi);
    TextView txtNewGroupEntry = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txtGroupRename);
    if(isNew==true){
        builder.setTitle("New Group");
        txtNewGroupEntry.setText(R.string.new_group_instruction);
    }
    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok_button, null);
    builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel_button, null);
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
    Button okButton = dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
```

I have an alert dialog with an add button and a cancel button. I want both of the button's text to be bold and italic. How can I do it?

Comment: make custom Alertdialog. follow this link http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/

Comment: Please post some code and explain what you have tried so far.

Comment: I use default dialog because I don't want to customize a lot of code. Is there only this way?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Instead of setting the button text to be `"add"`, set it to be `Html.fromHtml("<b><i>add</i></b>")`

So for with your code:

Change these lines:

```
builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok_button, null);
// and
builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel_button, null);
```

To these lines:

```
builder.setPositiveButton(Html.fromHtml("<b><i>" + getString(R.string.ok_button) + "</i><b>"), null);
// and 
builder.setNegativeButton(Html.fromHtml("<b><i>" + getString(R.string.cancel_button) + "</i><b>"), null);
```

---

**OR**

you could modify the Strings in your `strings.xml` file.

So for example, if your strings looked like this:

```xml
<string name="ok_button">add</string>
<string name="cancel_button">cancel</string>
```

you could change them to this:

```
<string name="ok_button"><b><i>add</i></b></string>
<string name="cancel_button"><b><i>cancel</i></b></string>
```

*but*

you still are referencing your Strings resources incorrectly. Instead of `R.string.ok_button`, because that returns an int, you would have to use `getString(R.string.ok_button)`

So you would have to change these lines:

```
builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok_button, null);
// and
builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel_button, null);
```

To these lines:

```
builder.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.ok_button), null);
// and
builder.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.cancel_button), null);
```

Comment: I work fine for me, but when I change the English text to Korean text it does not show in Italic.

Comment: @user3098538 I'm not sure why that would be. Try both methods in my answer and if neither of them work for Korean text, post it as another question and someone else could answer it for you.

Comment: I tried already but it is still the same. Thank for your advise.

Comment: Using an integer for the button text is not incorrect, that's a perfectly valid thing to do (pass a string resource)

Answer (score 21):

this sample code will help you...

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("message").setTitle("title");
    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            switch (which) {
            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                // do work
                break;
            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL:
                // do work
                break;
            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                // do work
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    };
    alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Yes", listener);
    alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "No", listener);
    alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "Cancel",
            listener);
    alertDialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {

        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
            AlertDialog alertDialog = (AlertDialog) dialog;
            Button button = alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
            button.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD | Typeface.ITALIC);

            button = alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
            button.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD | Typeface.ITALIC);

            button = alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL);
            button.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD | Typeface.ITALIC);
        }
    });
    alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: Yes it works fine for me too. Thank you! but it has problem with Korean text for showing in italic.

Answer (score 8):

You can access your `Dialog's` `buttons` within `onShow()` like I mentioned in below. At time of `onShow()` triggering you are able to access yoir dialog's UI, try this,

```
private void showAlertDialog(){

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

    builder.setMessage("Dailog Demo!");

    builder .setCancelable(false)
      .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
           dialog.cancel();
       }
   })
   .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
           dialog.cancel();
       }
   });

    final AlertDialog alertdialog = builder.create();
    alertdialog.setOnShowListener(new OnShowListener() {

        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
            ((Button)alertdialog.getButton(Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE)).setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
            ((Button)alertdialog.getButton(Dialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE)).setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
        }
    });
    alertdialog.show();
}
```

Comment: He also wants italics. And you're not even using his code. You just copied and pasted your own...

Comment: good answer it worked with me , but no need to cast (Button) coz the method getButton is return Button object

Comment: awesome, saved me lots of time